# How to delete account for which I have no access?

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts

I want to delete the first account:

[image]

I am not able to log in (using manage) as I do not have access to the account.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: Are you admin? You must be to manage other accounts.

Comment: Agree with @ChanganAuto - if you're not an admin you won't have much luck.  Do `netplwiz.exe` or `lusrmgr.msc` give you the option to remove the account?

Comment: I am. It's my personal PC at home. I have access to everything on the machine. But I have not access to the account.

Comment: @Paulπ I will try tomorrow and let you know. I guess there is something left in the registers for the account that needs to be deleted.

Comment: @Paulπ the user is not listed there. The only place it appears is in the Settings -> Accounts -> Email & Accounts in the section "Accounts used by other apps"

Comment: Just to make it 100% clear, you're trying to remove the first account in the picture (the "work or school" account)?  Do you see the account in `Settings > Accounts > Access work or school` or in `Settings > Accounts > Other users` or in `Settings > Accounts > Family` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try from System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> User Profiles

Or Start -> Run -> "SystemPropertiesAdvanced" -> User Profiles(Settings)